# Ninject not proving params to my Controller, after doing mass update with NuGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, nuget

I have an MVC4 project in which I use Ninject. I just use the Ninject MVC3-provided `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file, in the `App_Start` folder. I just performed a mass dependency update, with NuGet, without realizing how much trouble it might cause. It broke my Ninject setup, somehow. Prior to running the NuGet update, Ninject would properly create my controllers and provide them with the required constructor params. Now, after the update, I get the following error:

```
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +110

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Portal.Web.Controllers.MatterController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +247
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +438
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +226
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +326
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

The code inside of the `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file is being executed still, though. I can place breakpoints on it, and watch it apply my bindings. I don't think MVC is using it when creating controllers anymore, though.

Does anybody have any idea what might have been broken by this NuGet update?

Comment: Did you update to MVC5 without knowing? I performed that update accidentally too and it broke SimpleInjector.

Comment: Oh crap, yea that's what it is. Thanks! Didn't think about NuGet managing MVC versions, too.

Comment: I haven't put any effort in fixing it yet, since I rolled back to MVC4 so I can't help you further.

Comment: I too am trying to roll back to MVC4 somehow.

Comment: Long-live source control..